# Call Solr JSON Request API through HTTP request

Tags: curl, solr, lucene

I have a requirement to call Solr JSON Request API through a HTTP request instead of Curl command.

e.g. Sample Curl command which will give Solr result:

```
curl http://localhost:port/solr/collection/select -d 'json={query:"id:1"}&wt=json'
```

I know the equivalent Solr HTTP query is
`http://localhost:port/solr/collection/select?q=id:1`

But my original Solr JSON Request API have multiple parameters and wanted to know if I can call it directly using HTTP (without converting the query like above).

Something Like: `http://localhost:port/solr/collection/select?json={query:"id:1"}`

How can I do this? is it possible?

Comment: you mean to put HTTP url directly into browser? or looking for a client that can take full json as parameter?

Comment: If you cannot use an already existing client (like SolrJ) or translate all your JSON requests in Solr plain URL, all you can do is just move your curl HTTP posts in the equivalent requests done in the programming language you must use.

Comment: @SabirKhan I'm open for options (Wants to know all possible ways). But I'm not sure if there is an option to put in as a direct HTTP url in browser. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @freedev Yeah we are doing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl -d (or --data) is just sending a POST request to Solr. If you want to do the same in java just:

- use your preferred http library (like [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or any other) and by using it's api set it to be POST type request and add needed data.
- or you can just use plain java, it's just more verbose, [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) is an example